# Why does currentBuild.build().getActions(ParametersAction).get(0) return default parameter values rather the specified values in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying the change a parameter value in a Jenkins pipeline.  Here's my latest script code:

```
// Replace spaces in PROJECT_NAME parameter with dashes
script {
    def build = currentBuild.build()
    def parms = build.getActions(ParametersAction).get(0)
    for (ParameterValue parm : parms.getParameters()) {
        StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder()
        msg.append(parm.getName())
        msg.append(": ")
        if (parm.getValue() == null) {
            msg.append("<null>")                           
        } else {
            msg.append(String.valueOf(parm.getValue()))   
        }
        print(msg)
    }
    def projectNameWithoutSpaces = new StringParameterValue("PROJECT_NAME", "${params.PROJECT_NAME}".replaceAll(" ", "-"))
    build.replaceAction(parms.createUpdated(Arrays.asList(projectNameWithoutSpaces)))
}
```

I'm finding that `parms` contains the default parameter values rather than the values specified in the pipeline build.  This, in turn, is causing `build.replaceAction(parms.createUpdated(Arrays.asList(projectNameWithoutSpaces)))` to replace all parameter values except for the `PROJECT_NAME` value with the parameter's default value.

Why does `parms` contain default parameter values rather than the values specified in the pipeline build?  How do I get the specified parameter values so that I can correctly change the value of the PROJECT_NAME parameter?

Comment: Why do you need to go through the API? If you want to change a parameter value you could simply assign to `env.PARAMETERNAME`.

Comment: The values are available already in the `params` map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a user error on my part; `currentBuild.build().getActions(ParametersAction).get(0)` **does** return the correct parameter values.  It turns out that one of my earlier failed attempts had set all of my pipeline's parameter values, except for the PROJECT_NAME parameter value, to their default values.

One side effect of using `build.replaceAction()` is that it actually changes the pipeline build's PROJECT_NAME parameter value in the Jenkins web client.  So when I go to do a rebuild, the PROJECT_NAME parameter has the update value (spaces replaced with dashes), which is really not what I want.

Also, early on I tried the simpler solution of simply setting `params.PROJECT_NAME` to the new value:

```
// Replace spaces in PROJECT_NAME parameter with dashes
script {
    params.PROJECT_NAME = "${params.PROJECT_NAME}".replaceAll(" ", "-")
}
```

However, this failed with an `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` as the `params` object is backed by `java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap`.

I wasn't aware that the pipeline parameters values are also available via the `env` object (thanks to zett42 for pointing this out).  So I tried setting `env.PROJECT_NAME`:

```
// Replace spaces in PROJECT_NAME parameter with dashes
script {
    env.PROJECT_NAME = "${env.PROJECT_NAME}".replaceAll(" ", "-")
}
```

This worked just fine **without** changing the pipeline build's PROJECT_NAME parameter value in the Jenkins web client.